# How to distribute an application with ImageMagick dlls

Tags: windows, imagemagick, redistributable

I'm trying to distribute ImageMagick as part of an application to be run on a Windows XP machine.  A call to MagickReadImage returns MagickFalse, although the image is definitely present and not corrupt and the MagickWand from NewMagicWand is apparently valid.  This call works on a machine with ImageMagick installed.  The target machine will not have the ImageMagick package installed; we want to provide only the required .dll files to convert from .bmp to .jpeg.  We have not been able to get this working, and are assuming that we are missing a piece of the puzzle.  Is there a configuration step we're missing?  In other words, what needs to be where on the target machine?  We've copied the following dlls to the Windows\system32 directory:

- CORE_RL_bzlib_.dll
  CORE_RL_jpeg_.dll
  CORE_RL_Icms.dll
   CORE_RL_magick_.dll
  CORE_RL_ttf_.dll
   CORE_RL_wand_.dll
  CORE_RL_zlib_.dll
   IM_MOD_RL_bmp_.dll
  IM_MOD_RL_jpeg_.dll
   mfc100.dll
  msvcr100.dll
   vcomp100.dll
   X11.dll

The code in question is:

```
   m_pMagick_wand=NewMagickWand();

   m_mbStatus=MagickReadImage(m_pMagick_wand,fileName);
   if (m_mbStatus == MagickFalse)
   {
      TRACE("MagickFalse 1\n");
      return;
   }
```